# Group by specific value and return results in generated column

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to figure out how I can pull this off, but I have no clue how to do it.

I have a table (below) that has object_id's, types and values. The values are always unique and the type is always type1, type2 or type3.

```
id   object_id   type    value
---------------------------------
1    1           type1   123
2    1           type2   456
3    2           type3   789
```

The end result I'm trying to get is to consolidate all object_id's and return the types associated in "virtual columns" which are type1, type2, and type3.

```
object_id   type1  type2  type3
-----------------------------
   1        123    456    null
   2        null   null   789
```

Not sure if this is possible in mySql or if i should just try and build this in PHP instead. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table test (
 id int,
 object_id int,
 type varchar(5),
 val  int
);

insert into test values (1,1,'type1',123);
insert into test values (2,1,'type2',456);
insert into test values (3,2,'type3',789)

select t.object_id,
       max(t.type1) type1,
       max(t.type2) type2,
       max(t.type3) type3
  from (
 select object_id,
        case
        when type = 'Type1' then val
        end Type1,
        case
        when type = 'Type2' then val
        end Type2,
        case
       when type = 'Type3' then val
       end Type3
  from test
 ) t
group by t.object_id
```

[db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ue47QLXujjskGnwiYBCRMW/1)

If you have more then one record for the same id, object_id, and type, this will take the max, which may or may not be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   object_id,
   (SELECT b1.value FROM below b1 WHERE b1.object_id=b0.object_id and b1.type='type1') as Type1,
   (SELECT b1.value FROM below b1 WHERE b1.object_id=b0.object_id and b1.type='type2') as Type2,
   (SELECT b1.value FROM below b1 WHERE b1.object_id=b0.object_id and b1.type='type3') as Type3
FROM below b0
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=98618f2a316933c6c73260b13e33f15c
or

```
SELECT 
  b0.object_id,
  b1.value as Type1,
  b2.value as Type2,
  b3.value as Type3
FROM below b0
LEFT JOIN below b1 ON b1.object_id=b0.object_id and b1.type='type1'
LEFT JOIN below b2 ON b2.object_id=b0.object_id and b2.type='type2'
LEFT JOIN below b3 ON b3.object_id=b0.object_id and b3.type='type3'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0437e739f9a9d4cd9923feae6ecd5593

Comment: Add grouping and aggregate functions to the last query. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b0ad6a4d62a3a6e08b5755dee34c737). 1st may be modified by such way too, but it looks like a bad practice example.